# Summarize numbers in string with same category

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string in array values, which contains numbers with different categories:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
   echo "$key"." => "."$val";
}
```

and result like this:

```
5009263014 => DAT:20190917,INIT: 48.19,PAY: 48.19,WRT: 0.00,OPEN: 0.00,INV: 50.19,WAER:USD,RECIN:00000000,OP:020212526890,XBL:5006050942-239-6,FAED:20190816,DAT:20190823,INIT: 249.00,PAY: 249.00,WRT: 0.00,OPEN: 0.00,INV: 49.00,WAER:USD,RECIN:00000000,OP:020272550202,XBL:5006050942-238-8,FAED:20190715,DAT:20190823,INIT: 249.00,PAY: 249.00,WRT: 0.00,OPEN: 0.00,INV: 49.00,WAER:USD,RECIN:0000000
```

I would like to summarize all values, but only for few categories and place them into single category name. Those categories with summarized numbers are: INIT, PAY, WRT, OPEN, INV, and if possible, delete everything else in that string.

I dont know where to start here, thinking of explode function, but that will create additional arrays, maybe its more elegant to deal with reg exp?

Final result would look something like this:

```
5009263014 => INIT: 546.19, PAY: 546.19, WRT: 0.00, OPEN: 0.00, INV: 148.19
```

Comment: explode `$val` and loop through new array and you can do your operation and store in aother new array.

Comment: Can you please share of what you tried? maybe naive solution with the explode function?

Comment: "_but that will create additional arrays_" What's wrong with additional arrays?

Comment: can you also post the array itself ?

Comment: How did you store/create this string  ?

Comment: Im still grasping operations with arrays, so i prefer functions which deals with strings

Comment: please post the raw array, not just what you get with the foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = '5009263014 => DAT:20190917,INIT: 48.19,PAY: 48.19,WRT: 0.00,OPEN: 0.00,INV: 50.19,WAER:USD,RECIN:00000000,OP:020212526890,XBL:5006050942-239-6,FAED:20190816,DAT:20190823,INIT: 249.00,PAY: 249.00,WRT: 0.00,OPEN: 0.00,INV: 49.00,WAER:USD,RECIN:00000000,OP:020272550202,XBL:5006050942-238-8,FAED:20190715,DAT:20190823,INIT: 249.00,PAY: 249.00,WRT: 0.00,OPEN: 0.00,INV: 49.00,WAER:USD,RECIN:0000000';

preg_match_all('/(INIT|PAY|WRT|OPEN|INV):\s[\d.,]+/', $str, $m);

$res = implode('',$m[0]);

echo $res; // INIT: 48.19,PAY: 48.19,WRT: 0.00,OPEN: 0.00,INV: 50.19,INIT: 249.00,PAY: 249.00,WRT: 0.00,OPEN: 0.00,INV: 49.00,INIT: 249.00,PAY: 249.00,WRT: 0.00,OPEN: 0.00,INV: 49.00,
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it with several `explode`s:

```php
$array = ['5009263014' => 'DAT:20190917,INIT: 48.19,PAY: 48.19,WRT: 0.00,OPEN: 0.00,INV: 50.19,WAER:USD,RECIN:00000000,OP:020212526890,XBL:5006050942-239-6,FAED:20190816,DAT:20190823,INIT: 249.00,PAY: 249.00,WRT: 0.00,OPEN: 0.00,INV: 49.00,WAER:USD,RECIN:00000000,OP:020272550202,XBL:5006050942-238-8,FAED:20190715,DAT:20190823,INIT: 249.00,PAY: 249.00,WRT: 0.00,OPEN: 0.00,INV: 49.00,WAER:USD,RECIN:0000000'];

$toSum = ['INIT', 'PAY', 'WRT', 'OPEN', 'INV'];
$sums = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
   $values = explode(',', $val);
   foreach($values as $value) {
       list($sumKey, $sumVal) = array_map('trim', explode(':', $value));
       if (in_array($sumKey, $toSum)) {
           if (!isset($sums[$sumKey])) {
               $sums[$sumKey] = $sumVal;
               continue;
            }
            $sums[$sumKey] += $sumVal;
       }
   }
}

var_dump($key, $sums);
```

You can play or give us some tips [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a7bf6a92386751807aeac4504cdcb003c2cc7497)

Comment: It outputs correct numbers of array elements, but arrays are empty:

Comment: Forgot explode for the `,`

Comment: Yea, misunderstood the test data. Fixed.

Comment: @Greedy can you update your question with exact array input, with some more elements, than. For me it works fine in a sandbox with one element you provided. You can also use iquid207 regex solution and combine it with mine. I hope, you got the idea.

Comment: Also added `trim`, if input data is messed somehow

Comment: I've just updated my answer to make it more input-independent. Should be fine now.